# Overlapping repeating image in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the image (a) and I want it to overlap like in (b) with an offset. But I end up with (c)

[image]

This code gives me (c)

```
UIImage * imgLeftBorder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"border_left"];

 UIView * leftBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, screenHeight - 25)];
    [leftBorder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imgLeftBorder]];
    [self.view addSubview:leftBorder];
```

I have toyed with offsets and insets, but I am unable to achieve my result. Anyone ever do anything like this?

Comment: You are probably better of not using colorWithPatternImage:. I would try placing the UIViews yourself and calculate the Y of every UIView yourself.
Where, Y = "number of UIViews already placed" minus "a small offset to make it overlap".

Answer (score 0):

What about just using a while?

```
int currY = 0;

while(currY < screenHeight) {
    UIImageView *leftBorder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, currY, imgLeftBorder.size.width, imgLeftBorder.size.width)];
    leftBorder.image = imgLeftBorder;
    [self.view addSubview:leftBorder];
    currY += imgLeftBorder.size.width - 25;
}
```